# Format exception was unhandled. Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am getting an error "Format exception was unhandled." and "Input string was not in a correct format." It is in this line temp_i = float.Parse(textBox3.Text); What is the problem?

```
//button 2 calculate button
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  float temp_e;
  float temp_i;
  float temp_r;
  float temp_p;

  //*******************************************************
  // Resistance = Volts / Current
  //*******************************************************
  if (IsNumeric(textBox1.Text) &&
  IsNumeric(textBox2.Text) &&
  textBox3.Text == (""))
  {
    temp_e = float.Parse(textBox1.Text); //convert string to number
    temp_i = float.Parse(textBox3.Text); //convert string to number

    temp_r = temp_e / temp_i; //display 1st result
    textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(temp_r);  //post result resistance (R)

    //calculate power
    temp_p = temp_e * temp_i;
    textBox5.Text = Convert.ToString(temp_p);

    //display 2nd result
    textBox4.Text = Convert.ToString(temp_r) + " * " + Convert.ToString(temp_i) + " = " + Convert.ToString(temp_p) + " watts";
  }'
```

Comment: How would you want to convert " " to float ? are you sure ? Try removing that condition in if else Parse and compare it.

Answer (score 4):

```
temp_i = float.Parse(textBox3.Text); //convert string to numbe
```

`textBox3.Text` certainly contains "" because it was in your if condition.

You can't parse "" to float.

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be obvious; `textbox3.Text` contains a value which is not valid to be passed to `float.Parse`. In your case, an empty string (based on the `if` just above it!

Answer (score 0):

You check whether the textbox is empty and if it is, you're trying to convert to float? Check your logic.

I guess you was trying to do this:

```
temp_i = float.Parse(textBox2.Text);
```

Which would make more sense :)